How to achieve dynamic type on prisma
Showing this expression is not callable error.
How to resolve this type error on findUnique method while dynamic models.
export const isFound = async (
  model: Prisma.ModelName,
  id: string | number,
  idName: string
): Promise<boolean> => {
  id = parseInt(id as string)
  const result = await prisma[model].findUnique({
    where: { [idName]: id },
  })
  return !!result
}

I tried with any type. its working fine. but i want more type safety.
how to achieve without error
 await (prisma[model] as any).findUnique({
    where: { [idName]: id },
  })

i want something like that
 await (prisma[model] as GoodType).findUnique({
    where: { [idName]: id },
  })


I think you can't.
Since prisma is strongly typed, the findUnique of each entity have really different input and output types. You might succeed by rewrite a full wrapper, with many generics. and that exactly what prisma is ... You will re-write a bad typed prisma
The cast you actually use is working only by luck

You can't. It's not supported.
A slightly longer version:
You can keep using typecasting as any if you wish, but there is no way to achieve type. One option you may want to look at is raw queries and specifically the queryRawUnsafe() and parametrized queries (documentation).
I'd advise to consider why you would need dynamic table names and if yes, then re-evaluating if Prisma is a right match for your scenario.
